# Is there a Unix equivalent of the Windows environment variable PATHEXT

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I am wondering if there is a Unix equivalent for the Windows environment variable `PATHEXT`.

For those with no Windows background: Adding a file suffix to `PATHEXT` allows me to execute a script without typing that suffix in cmd.exe. For example, on my Windows computer, PATHEXT contains the suffix `.pl` and when I want to execute a Perl script in cmd.exe, I simply can type `my-script` and it gets executed. Yet, in order to execute the same script in bash, I need to write the full name: `my-script.pl`.

Since I work on both Windows and Unix currently, I almost always fall into the trap of forgetting to type the suffix when going to a Unix box again.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what Windows did if PATHEXT contained, for example, .sh and .pl and you tried to run 'foo' in a directory with foo.sh and foo.pl in it.

Comment: If `.sh` preceedes `.pl`, `foo.sh` will be run. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7839178/180275

Comment: I have the same experience in WSL: it's unusual that I remember to type `git.exe` instead of `git`, and if `git` were the only one then an alias would be a fine solution, but I think I'll try the `.bashrc` solution below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really want to do it, there is a way. Add the following at the end of `.bashrc` in your home directory, and set `PATHEXT` to extension names with dots separated by `:`. (Changed to include the dots to match the Windows behavior.) Use it at your own risk.

```
if declare -f command_not_found_handle >/dev/null; then 
    eval "original_command_not_found_handle() $(declare -f command_not_found_handle|tail -n +2)"
fi
command_not_found_handle(){
    local PATHEXT_EXPANDED i
    IFS=: read -a PATHEXT_EXPANDED<<<"$PATHEXT"
    for i in "${PATHEXT_EXPANDED[@]}"; do
        if type "$1$i" &>/dev/null; then
            "$1$i" "${@:2}"
            return $?
        fi
    done
    if declare -f original_command_not_found_handle >/dev/null; then
        original_command_not_found_handle "$@"
    else
        return 127
    fi
}
```

Also remember that you can use tab to complete the command name if there isn't another command also starting with `my-script`.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution is to just not use extensions for your scripts. They are not necessary and only serve to identify the script's type to you, but not to the computer. While Windows uses extensions to identify the file type, *nix systems (with very few exceptions such as `gzip`) do not.

Note that binaries have no `.exe` extension in *nix, they're just called `foo`, not `foo.exe`. So, if you want `foo.pl` to be executable as `foo`, simply save the file as `foo` in the first place.

Alternatively, if you really need to have the extensions for some reason, go into whatever directory you save your scripts in and run this:

```
for f in *.*; do ln -s "$f" "${f%%.*}"; done
```

That will iterate over all files with extensions and, for each file `foo.ext` of them, will create a link called `foo` which points to `foo.ext`. Note that this will fail if you have multiple scripts with the same name but different extensions.

Answer (score 8):

short: no

longer: shell scripts require a full filename, but you can define aliases for your commands to refer to them by various names.  For example

```
alias my-script=my-script.pl
```